# How do I access Azure Storage container from Azure Cognitive services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-services

I am having an issue with transcribing (Speech-To-Text) an audio file hosted on Azure Storage container from the Cognitive Services API.

The services are of the same resource (and I created a VNet and they are part of the same subnet).

[image: API request to cognitive services]

After I take the response from there the contentUrl:
[image: Response from getting the transcription]

The error I get is:

```
    {
      "successfulTranscriptionsCount": 0,
      "failedTranscriptionsCount": 1,
      "details": [
        {
        "source":"https://{service-name}.blob.core.windows.net/meetingnotes/Meeting82035.wav",
        "status": "Failed",
        "errorMessage": "Error when downloading the recording URI. StatusCode: Conflict.",
        "errorKind": "DownloadRecordingsUrisUnknownError"
        }
      ]
     }
```

Comment: Hello @Hasam , Can you try providing the cognitive services system-identity or user-assigned identity , a rbac role i.e.  storage account contributor role or storage blob contributor role.

Comment: Please Provide the blob SAS Url not the blob url.

Comment: Hello @Hasam,Please let me know if you are still facing any issue. You can accept it as an answer it the provided answer does help you so that it will help other community member as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Azure support and they provided the correct solution, which is to add the Role “Storage Blob Data Contributor” to the speech services resources.

Go to IAM of your storage account

[image]

Go to Role Assignments

[image]

click "Add", then add your speech service in Managed Identities.
That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I tested in my environment and was getting the same error as you.

[image]

***To resolve the issue, you need to append the `SAS Token` with `bloUrl` in `contentUrls` field.***

[image]

For Generating the SAS token allowed all the permission as I have done in below picture.

[image]

[image]

Generated Transcript report

[image]

Final `OutPut` Once Clicked on `ContentUrl`

[image]

Comment: I have tried this method it does not work for me